# There are no [rooms] left

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There's a tag called [rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rooms). It currently has 12 questions, most of which are actually on topic, but the tag seems to match most of the [burnination criteria.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)

The tag doesn't have a tag wiki at the moment, but it seems most of the questions using the tag are about some sort of virtual room (chat room, etc.), which don't seem to add any extra meaning to the questions and is not unambiguous in all contexts.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It does describe the topic of the question in most cases, but it is quite ambiguous (it could be used for a question on how to make the 3D model of a room programatically or it could be about chat rooms, etc.).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   If the tag had a common, more specific meaning (such as chat-rooms), it could be, but in its current form, I believe no.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Due to the ambiguity around the whole tag, it's hard to say that anyone would be following the tag (no followers atm) or that it would help anyone find a question or even clarify the topic of a question using the tag.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No, rooms is a really generic term that could have very different meanings in different contexts, such as the ones described in the first point.

Can we burninate this tag?

Comment: Maybe we could discuss making `rooms` a synonym of `chatroom` (after removing it from the appropriate questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through all of them manually. The [rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rooms) was being used for multiple (ambiguous) reasons. Some of them being:

- posts related to chatrooms. Using the [chatroom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatroom) was appropriate here.
- A chat application, but had mentions of chatrooms. Using the [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat) is appropriate here.
- Socket.io rooms and namespaces. Using the [socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) tag was enough here.
- Android Room persistent library. We need to use the [android-room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-room) tag for this.
- Some applications where the OP has used a variable room.

I closed the off-topic posts, retagged the salvagable ones and deleted the unsalvagable ones. [rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rooms) has been *burninated*.

[image]